# It's the new me or a new me?

Tags: articles

In the movie [*Source Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code) is a guy who's got control over another man's body and gets to talk to a woman who's traveling with; she becomes unconvinced about the man's behavior which is not qutie the same as she's known and says:

> Who are you and what did you do to Sean Fentress?

To which the man murmurs to himself:

> It's the new me.

Why did he say *the new me* instead of *a new me*?

Comment: Because there's only one of him.  If he was speculating about some change in his future self he might use "a new me" to refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "a" is indefinite, used for non-specific things.  Like "I want **a** carrot."  That means that I don't care which carrot I get, as long as I get a carrot.  meanwhile "I want **the** carrot" means I want a specific carrot and I won't be happy until I get the right carrot.

So "It's a new me" doesn't make sense unless you only know you want change, not what change you want.  if you are a new person in specific ways, say

> It's the new me.

If you want to be new, but don't know how yet, say

> It's/It'll be a new me.